# Implementing Video streaming restrictions based on hourly usage at home

Tags: networking, router, wireshark, access-control

I'm new at networking, so my question might be basic or naive.

I want to implement restrictions for mobile devices if it is being used to view videos for more than an hour continuously then its internet access should be disconnected and a login window should be shown to enter a password to regain the internet access.

The hardware setup at my home is I have TP-link ER605 Router and then a D-link Dir-1960 A1 wifi as access point.

Now what is the best way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

As per my google search, it is suggested that I need a network monitoring tool like Wireshark and then a custom script to interact with it and to implement the restrictions, but for this to work it would need a device like raspberry pi.